# uiOutput ignores <head> or <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html, r, api, shiny

I am trying to include an Outdooractive(.com) map in my Shiny app via Outdooractive's API, which uses an html page with a script tag in the header and a JavaScript tag in the body.

When using Outdooractive's html template, saving it as an html file and then including it in a Shiny App via `includeHTML("originalFile.html")`, the map is displayed correctly. However, since I want the coordinates for the map to be interactive (without saving it to file in-between), I tried to create the html in a `renderUI` using shiny tags, and display it via `uiOutput`. When doing so, the JavaScript part does not seem to be processed at all. The header above the map is shown, as is the text below it, but the map is ignored without error message. Interestingly, the same happens when I replace the tag `tags$head` by `tags$header`.

Here is my `app.R`:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Outdooractive Map"),

    # Sidebar with a text input for coordinates
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput ("lng",
                        "Longitude:",
                       value = "10.000",
                    ),
            textInput("lat",
                      "Latitude:",
                      value = "45.555")
        ),

        # Show the map 
        mainPanel(
            #includeHTML("originalFile.html") # This works
            textOutput("text"), # This shows the correct longitude/latitude
            uiOutput("map") # This seems to ignore the script
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to access API
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$map <- renderUI({
        lng = input$lng
        lat = input$lat
        
        tags$html(
            tags$div(
                tags$head(tags$title("Test"),
                          HTML('<meta charset="utf-8">'),
                          tags$script(
                              src = '//www.outdooractive.com/alpportal/oa_head.js?proj=api-dev-oa&amp;key=yourtest-outdoora-ctiveapi&amp;lang=en'
                          ),
                          tags$style(HTML(
                              '.oax .oax-cluster-marker-cont, .oax-cluster-marker-cont {background-color: red;}'
                          ))),
                tags$body(
                    h2("Outdooractive Routes"),
                    div(class = 'oax-top-cont'),
                    tags$script(HTML(paste(
                        'var conf = {frontendtype: "tour", zoom: 11, center:[ ', lng, ", ",  lat, ']}; var fvp = oa.api.flexviewpage( conf );')
                    )),
                    HTML('There should be a map on top of me.')
                )
            ),

        )
    })
    
    output$text <- renderText ({
        paste(input$lng, input$lat)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

To fully replicate the example, this would be the `originalFile.html` (which works when line 23 in `app.R` is uncommented):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>outdooractive platform - API Template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    
    <!-- load Outdooractive Javascript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="//www.outdooractive.com/alpportal/oa_head.js?proj=api-dev-oa&amp;key=yourtest-outdoora-ctiveapi&amp;lang=en"></script>


    <style>
      .oax .oax-cluster-marker-cont, .oax-cluster-marker-cont {
          background-color: red;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
  <br>
  <br>
    <h2>Outdooractive Routes</h2>

    <!-- container used by FlexView API -->
    <div class="oax-top-cont"></div>


    <!-- and some lines of javascript inside a script tag -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var conf = {
          frontendtype:   "tour",          // choose content type
          zoom:           11,              // set initial zoom level
          center:       [ 10.292, 47.546 ] // set initial map center
      };
      
      var fvp = oa.api.flexviewpage( conf );

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather call some `JavaScript` in an observer:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(glue)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
   useShinyjs(),
   includeHTML("header.html"), ## see comment
   titlePanel("Outdooractive Map"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         textInput ("lng",
                    "Longitude:",
                    value = "10.000",
         ),
         textInput("lat",
                   "Latitude:",
                   value = "45.555")
      ),
      mainPanel(
         div(
            class = "oax-top-cont"
         )
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {  
   observe({
      script <- glue("var conf = {{",
                     "frontendtype: 'tour',",
                     "zoom: 11,",
                     "center: [{input$lng}, {input$lat}]",
                     "}};",
                     "var fvp = oa.api.flexviewpage(conf);"
      )
      runjs(script)
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

Some remarks:

- The use of `shinyjs` makes using `JavaScript` in `R` a piece of cake. You need to call `useShinyjs` somewhere in your `UI` and then you can issue arbitrary `JS` code via `runjs`.
- I use an observer, which calls the respective `JS` function whenever `lat` and/or `lng` change and moved the static part (i.e. the loading of the API and the `css` to the UI.
- **Important Note.** Initially, I used the following snippet in my `UI` instead of `includeHTML`:

```r
tags$head(
   tags$script(
      type = "text/javascript",
      src  = "//www.outdooractive.com/alpportal/oa_head.js?proj=api-dev-oa&amp;key=yourtest-outdoora-ctiveapi&amp;lang=en"
   ),
   tags$style(...)
)
```

- However, this failed to load the `JS` from outdooractive and I got response code `403` (forbidden), i.e. outdoor denied my request. My guess is that this is due to using the test account. For whatever funny reason hardcoding that bit in a html file and using `includeHTML` seems to work (again I can simply guess, but I assume that outdooractive tries somehow to figure out whether you are using the test account just locally or already in production. And maybe the `tags$script` part fails this test, while the static approach passes this test, but this is just a pure guess from my side - more importantly `includeHTML` workaround works. But you should try to replace the keys by your own ones and see whether you still need the `includeHTML` part or you can directly use `tags$script in your` UI`):

```r
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="//www.outdooractive.com/alpportal/oa_head.js?proj=api-dev-oa&amp;key=yourtest-outdoora-ctiveapi&amp;lang=en">
</script>
<style>
   .oax .oax-cluster-marker-cont, .oax-cluster-marker-cont {
       background-color: red;
   }
</style>
```

---

#### Update

I add a gif of how the app look here in Chrome:

[image: App Gif]

Comment: Thank you so much for this! The map is now correctly displaying the map with the originally defined coordinates, but did it react appropriately when you changed the coordinates interactively? When I do, the map jumps to the right a bit and then back to the original coordinates, as if the new `JS` were constantly overwritten by the old one. Could that be the case? If so, is there a way to stop the old script before running the updated one?

Comment: When I change the coordinates the map will be redrawn showing the center coordinates as selected in the inputs. This happens while you type, so maybe you need `?debounce` to react not immediately on the text input change but only fater soem time?

Comment: I added an `actionButton` so that it would only process after I have entered the complete coordinate but still it would not update. Interestingly, it works once it is published online, which is all I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Strange, I added a gif showing how the the map transition works for me. There is no "jump to the right" at all.